# Can ping but can't otherwise reach PFsense clients on virtual bridge

Tags: networking, fedora, kvm-switch, pfsense, libvirt

I have a setup with a physical hypervisor running KVM + Libvirtd on Fedora 22. 
On this hypervisor, there's a PFsense VM and several other VMs interconnected on a virtual bridge. 
The PFsense VM is also bridged with the physical adapter. It is the only device that connects to the outer network. I intend to connect this setup directly to a fiber uplink on a WAN IP, and forward the ports for the VMs through the PFsense VM. Technical staff will also connect to the PFsense box over OpenVPN in order to reach the internal network.

However, in a testing environment I cannot access the machines forwarded through the PFsense box on the outer IP. I have tried everything and spend 6+ hours on it, and I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Here's the firewall rules, 10.42.0.0 is the bridge/LAN, 10.43.0.0 is VPN. The WAN_XS4ALLFTTH is the fiber PPPOE, WAN_NOVLAN is a testing environment:

[image: Firewall rules]

I can ping from 10.43.x.x to 10.42.x.x but not reach any services. 
I can ping the outer WAN_NOVLAN interface but not reach any services on it.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

If needed I can post the NAT rules but you should be able to guess them from the firewall rules with the 'NAT' description (auto generated).

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm having a very similar problem, with a bridge between the wired network and the wifi AP, and everything works except wifi hosts cannot talk to wired hosts (ping only).

Comment: It's been a while, and I haven't really used PFsense with kvm since, but if I recall correctly there was a compatibility issue between the virtual network drivers and freebsd. You could try using a different type of virtual adapter, e.g Intel or Realtek NIC emulation instead of the virtIO one. But it's been a while so take it with a grain of salt ;) @SkylarMT

Comment: @SkylarMT I booted up a PFsense VM on my KVM hypervisor. Everything seems to work, I can reach the PFsense webinterface from the clients, clients can talk with eachother and the internet.... but the performance is absolutely horrible, I can't get above 20mbit.. So not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, but at least it should be possible to have PFsense running under KVM and get communication, using the VirtIO Network drivers.

Comment: I have it installed on bare metal with the builtin motherboard NIC plus two PCI cards.  I'm using an old desktop with a Core 2 Duo and 1GB RAM, so you can probably see why I'm not using a VM :)
Still having the same problem as you did it seems, though.